Trying to quantize YOLOv11 in tensorflow, is this topology normal?
I'm trying to quantize the YOLO v11 model in tensorflow and get this as a result:


The target should be int8. Is this normal behaviour? When running it with tflite micro on an esp32 I quicly run out of memory, even though I allocate 5 MB (the model is 3MB). Could my problem be tied to this wierd topology? Or are there any ways to mitigate my memory issues? I'm a total noob, so any help is appreciated!

I'm currently dealing with the same project!
The topology is normal. Try modifying the ESP32 partition to fix this memory issue. Here is some reference:
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/partition-tables.html
I tried this partition, and it works well:
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
# Note: if you have increased the bootloader size, make sure to update the offsets to avoid overlap
nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x6000,
phy_init, data, phy,     0xf000,  0x1000,
factory,  app,  factory, 0x10000, 0x400000, 
model,    data,  ,       0x410000, 0x300000,  

Also check this issue in the esp-idf official repo:
https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/12588
I have to say that i cannot make inferences yet, i am currently dealing with some micro op resolver issues, but the project can be built.
I hope this contribution helps you!
